# Binding form to HTTP request with attributes containing '.' (dots/periods)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have want to have an endpoint which is called by a third party which the parameter names they will use can't be changed. The submitted data contains parameters with the character `.` (e.g. `hub.token`) along with others.

I had wanted to create a Django form to validate the callback but how does one write a form class which will bind to the request. Without noticing the problem I tried `hub.token` which does not work as `hub` dictionary does not exist. I then tried `hub_token` in the hope Django would recognise the intent.

Having a period in the attribute is valid as in HTML form submission the name is taken the controls name attribute which [can contain periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

**Is there an easy way to handle this situation without having to access each field in the view?**

---

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class RegisterEndpointForm(forms.Form):
    hub.token = forms.CharField()
```

---

views.py

```
...
register_request = RegisterEndpointForm(request.GET)
if register_request.is_valid()
    pass
...
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I don't thin you can set attributes containing dots. You could try a couple things. You could set the field as `hub_token`, then replace the dot with an underscore in request.GET. for example:

```
data = request.GET
data['hub_token'] = data['hub.token'] 
del data['hub.token']
register_request = RegisterEndpointForm(data)
…
```

You could also try setting the field dynamically on form init. For example:

```
class RegisterEndpointForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterEndpointForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['hub.token'] = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the from `__init__` option is best. I tried to avoid duplication the field names so have instead replaced all periods with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `__init__` method suggested by @jproffitt but replace all keys containing periods with underscores.

```
class RegisterEndpointForm(forms.Form):
    hub_verify_token = forms.CharField()
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterEndpointForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        all_fields = self.data.copy()
        for key, value in all_fields.iteritems():
            safe_key = key.replace('.', '_')
            if safe_key != key:
                    self.data[safe_key] = value
```